# How to terminate notifications when user logout

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I integrated Firebase Messaging using local notification in my app, when User A send friend request to User B ,, then User B receives notification. But the problem is when User B logout and User A send friend request to User B then notification also showing to User B even User B is logout.. So basically how can I terminate notifications when user is logout ??

I don't want to show notifications to Logout Users..

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are storing the tokens of each user right? If so just delete the token of the user, who just log out.

Comment: @quoci's solution above works.. for that you have to delete token from your backend when you call logout API if any...

or I think GCM service the way you register, there has to have some method to unregister=>
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getBaseContext());
            gcm.unregister();

Comment: @quoci yes token is stored in database ,, I delete the token on user logout but when the user login again the regenerated token not work

Comment: What error do you get? You have to simply add the token to the database if you login, and delete the token if you log out.

Comment: @quoci The problem is when user login they get notifications that great but when user logout the also get notifications ,, so when i remove token on logout then it works but the issue is When the same user login again they didn't get any notifications

Comment: Yeah I get it, but what error do you get? Usually you can just get the token from firebase and add it to the database again.

Comment: sir but the regenerated token didn't work again

Answer (score 3):

You can use FirebaseMessaging.deleteToken();

as shown in this linked
https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/deleteToken.html